# Sum up time in one column of excel hh:mm:ss.mss (mss is mili second in three figures)

Tags: javascript, html, xlsx

Hi i  have a time column in hh:mm:ss.mss format

which i want summed up and displayed as a table in html
also the table is

| Date | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 2/03/1994 | 00:01:31:109 |
| 2/03/1994 | 00:01:31:109 |
| 3/03/1994 | 00:02:31:109 |
| 3/03/1994 | 00:02:31:109 |

If any can help with syntax how to
display
table
2/03/1994 - sum of both time
3/03/1994 - sum of both time

```js
let table = document.querySelector(".table");
(
  async() => {
    let workbook = XLSX.read(await (await fetch("./Book.xlsx")).arrayBuffer());
    console.log(workbook);
    let worksheet = workbook.SheetNames;
    worksheet.forEach(name => {
      let html = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_html(workbook.Sheets[name]);
      table.innerHTML += `
                            <h3>${name}</h3>${html}
                            `;
    })
  }
)()
```

```html
<table class="table">
</table>
```